# Issues with MdTooltipModule

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've been getting the error Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule' problem and I'm not sure what is causing it.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MdTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MdTooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

That is my app.module.ts and I've looked at some other questions but it hasn't helped. It was working before I added MdTooltipModule so I'm not sure if that's causing an issue?

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at eval (compiler.js:15240)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15209)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34405)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34260)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5567)
    at eval (main.ts:11)
```

Comment: can you post the full error stack trace?

Comment: which version of `material` you are using?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal I'm using 5.2.4

Comment: in that case it would be `MatTooltipModule` added as answer. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `MatTooltipModule` rather than `MdTooltipModule`.

Comment: is it something they changed from version 2.0.0-beta.8?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.2.4/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip-module.ts